# how to fix angular ngFor using Float

Tags: angular

I m creating a rating system , the number of stars can be 3.5 , 4.5 ...I have wrote this code

```
<div class="rating"  >
    <i class="icon-star  voted" *ngFor="let j of Arr(item.nbEtoile); let i = index;"></i>                    
</div>
```

the problem is the website crushes, when item.nbEtoile became 3.5 or any other float number.

Comment: Don't call function in `*ngFor`. It'll be called multiple times than you intended.

Comment: so what shall i do instead ?

Comment: Could you please say what is the purpose of `Arr()` function? Apply that function in the controller and use the return value directly in the `*ngFor`

Comment: @computertricks Not sure what the `Arr` returns, but for sure you could use a `@Pipe` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to `round` your array before `ngFor`:

```
item.nbEtoile = item.nbEtoile.map(s=> Math.round(s));
```

and then iterate:

```
<div class="rating"  >
    <i class="icon-star  voted" 
        *ngFor="let j of item.nbEtoile; let i = index;"></i>                    
</div>
```

Comment: I would round the number rather than ceil it. You want 3 for 3.1, and 4 for 3.9.

Comment: @AntoineB thanks for the great comment. I've edited reply. Thanks!:)